# Emission particles disappear after first frame in animation render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, emission

For some odd reason, the snow in my scene is rendered only for the very first image output. Second frame and onward, the particle effects disappear. Please note that there are stars in the scene - the particles in the second image are not the snow that I desire.
[image: Image 1][image: Image 2]
This issue only applies to the product render of each frame. In my viewport, I am able to see snow particles / emission from start to end of its lifetime and full animation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by baking the emission under Cache tab. I also checked the Disk Cache option, which may or may not have contributed.